# вылезает segmentation fault. не понимаю где

Tags: c

```
const int bufferSize = 4096;
char buffer[bufferSize];
int currentFile = optind;
FILE *fp;

while (currentFile <= argc) {
if (currentFile != argc) {
    fp = fopen(argv[currentFile], "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s: net file",
        argv[0], argv[currentFile]);
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Без конкретного примера использования трудно сказать. Но скорее всего: неизвестно значение `optind`, значение `currentFile` больше чем `argc` и при обращении `argv[currentFile]` вы уходите за пределы массива.

Comment: А ещё показанный здесь цикл при определённых условиях является вечным, потому что значение `currentFile` внутри цикла не меняется

Comment: а может открывается такое большое кол-во файлов, что оно падает?