# при выполнении ./a.out в консоль выводится пустота. Если засунуть в онлайн компилятор то он выдает ELF. если посмотреть в другом то пишет "net file"

Tags: c

```
const int bufferSize = 4096;
char buffer[bufferSize];
int currentFile;
FILE *fp;

while (currentFile <= argc) {
if (currentFile != argc) {
    fp = fopen(argv[currentFile], "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s: net file",
        argv[0], argv[currentFile]);
        exit(1);
```

Comment: У вас `currentFile` вообще не инициализированная переменная, в ней может быть что угодно... 0 - пытается открыть сам выполнимый файл, больше `argc` - цикл вообще не работает. Кстати, зачем у вас такой странный подход — цикл с `<=`, а в нем проверка на (не)равенство? Делали бы просто цикл меньше. И потом, у вас явно не весь код приведен, надо понимать, пытаетесь читать кусок файла и выводить?

Comment: Причём ещё [четыре дня назад](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1416332) она была инициализированная...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [вылезает segmentation fault. не понимаю где](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1416332/%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-segmentation-fault-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%8e-%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Answer (score 1):

я бы написал проще и правильнее. argv именно меньше, а не меньше или равно. В С/С++ аргументы с нуля, выходите за границу массива

```
for(currentFile = 1; currentFile < argc; currentFile++){
 fp = fopen(argv[currentFile], "rb");
}
```

Comment: Не выходит: `if (currentFile != argc)`

Comment: что не выходит? Где?

Comment: у меня описка была, поправил в цикле было i < argc, а нужно currentFile < argc